# Replacing portions of a long string with different values

Tags: java, string, java-8

I have a string like below;

`String textToShow = "Appplication [%ApplicationName%]: started at [%Date%][%Time%]"`

Where i need to replace the Strings in between `[%` and `%]` with different values.

I did like below, but it works only the First one i.e. "ApplicationName".

```
private String getTextVariableName(String stringToShow) {
    if (stringToShow.contains("[%") && stringToShow.contains("%]")) {
        String content[] = notificationText.split("%");
        return content[1];
    }
    return null;
}

private String replaceValue(String stringToShow, String dataToReplace) {
    return stringToShow.substring(0, stringToShow.indexOf("["))
            + dataToReplace
            + stringToShow.substring(stringToShow.indexOf("]") + 1, stringToShow.length());
}

public String processText(String stringToShow, String appname) {
    String variableName = getTextVariableName(stringToShow);
    String processedText = "Invalid";
    if (variableName != null) {
        switch (variableName.toLowerCase()) {

        case "applicationname":
            processedText = replaceValue(stringToShow, appname);
            break;

        case "datetime":
            LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            String formattedCurrentDateTime = currentDateTime
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter
                            .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            processedText = replaceValue(stringToShow,
                    formattedCurrentDateTime);
            break;

        case "date":
            LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
            String formattedCurrentDate = currentDate
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            processedText = replaceValue(stringToShow,
                    formattedCurrentDate);
            break;

        case "time":
            LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
            String formattedCurrentTime = currentTime
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
            processedText = replaceValue(notificationText,
                    formattedCurrentTime);
            break;

        default:
            processedText = "Invalid";
            break;
        }
    }
    return processedText;
}
```

How can i make it work for the whole string without splitting it further and further if there are more portions similar to these appear?

Is there better method without splitting?

Note: I get this string from DataBase, so i cannot change the string. I just need to replace the portions between `[%` and `%]` according to the name of the string. Like, if it is a Date, it must be replace by date and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Regular Expression API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) offers the required logic, which you can use to replace an arbitrary number of variables in a string efficiently, see [appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and [appendTail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-):

```
public String processText(String stringToShow, String appname) {
    Matcher m=Pattern.compile("\\[%(\\w+)%\\]").matcher(stringToShow);
    if(!m.find()) return stringToShow;
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    do {
        String replacement;
        switch(m.group(1).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)) {
            case "applicationname":
                replacement=appname;
                break;
            case "datetime":
                replacement = LocalDateTime.now().format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                break;
            case "date":
                replacement = LocalDate.now().format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                break;
            case "time":
                replacement = LocalTime.now().format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
                break;
            default:
                replacement = "Invalid";
        }
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    } while(m.find());
    return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

Note that this API missed the introduction of `StringBuilder`, so we have to use `StringBuffer` here. That’s [solved in Java 9](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuilder-java.lang.String-).

---

Note that `appendReplacement` assigns a special meaning to `$` and `\` characters if they occur in the replacement string. If you suspect them to appear in a replacement string but want to insert the string literally, [`quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-) can be used, i.e. `m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement( replacement));`.

Comment: This is beautiful. Didn't knew about this. Thank You very much. I hope your answer will help lot of people as it helped me. :)

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
String textToShow = "Appplication [%ApplicationName%]: started at [%Date%][%Time%]"
textToShow = textToShow.replace("[%ApplicationName%]","your new string here");
textToShow = textToShow.replace("[%Date%]","your new date here");
textToShow = textToShow.replace("[%Time%]","your new time here");
```

much straight forward, easier and less error prune

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

So you can declare the format

```
private static final String FORMAT = "Appplication %s: started at %s%s"
```

And then, whenever you have to replace the `%s` with the string you can do

```
String.format(FORMAT, applicationName, date, time)
```

Comment: Actually that is not an option. I get this string from database. So i cannot change the string.